# While using appium how can we change device orientation to landscape mode?

Tags: ios, appium, landscape, orientation-changes, appium-ios

While using appium to test mobile application coded in Angular JS with protractor how can we change simulator orientation to landscape mode?
I have added : `'deviceorientation': 'landscape',` in `config.js` file.
But it didn't change when i run it.

Comment: Have you tried this : ((AppiumDriver) driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);

Comment: capability is just 'orientation', so use  **orientation:'LANDSCAPE'**

Comment: @4M01 : you are right my problem was because that and i didn't use uppercase ;)

Comment: @ShekharSwami : thanks for your try but i'm using it in capabilities in the config of protractor i'm not using ` AppiumDriver driver`

Comment: @Emna Glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it with uppercase in capabilities in the config file :

- `'orientation': 'LANDSCAPE'`

also with this option it is working :

- `'deviceorientation': 'LANDSCAPE'`

Answer (score 1):

Using server capabilities :

> ***orientation*** - (*`Sim/Emu-only`*) *start* in a certain orientation - ***LANDSCAPE or PORTRAIT***

and also as suggested by @Shekhar Swami using the code you can perform an action like :

```
(AppiumDriver)driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for landscape mode:

```
public void rotateDeviceScreenToLandscape() {
        ((Rotatable) driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry i'm using protractor not java and i've already resolved :) 
Thanks for your try

Answer (score 1):

In my case it switches the mode but device remains the same (vertically oriented). To fix that - go to Simulator window - Device - Rotate