# Appium/Protractor rotate screen on real device

Tags: javascript, android, automated-tests, protractor, appium

I am unable to rotate screen to landscape on **real device**. Tests are written in JS.

```
capabilities: {
  orientation: 'landscape',
  platformName: 'Android',
  platformVersion: '5.0.2',
  ...
},
```

Application is build using Ionic framework.

I am using such [configuartion](http://tombuyse.com/end-to-end-testing-an-ionic-application-with-appium-and-protractor/)

Has someone faced this problem before? Also is it available to change it on my test suite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While using appium how can we change device orientation to landscape mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167082/while-using-appium-how-can-we-change-device-orientation-to-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this one to your config file :

```
deviceorientation: 'LANDSCAPE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The orientation in your config file should be written in uppercase letters like that:

```
orientation: 'LANDSCAPE'
```

Comment: Such configuration works only for emulator/simulator not real device :)

Comment: @Laurynas : and with deviceorientation: 'LANDSCAPE' is it ok ?

Comment: No, it's not :/ For emulator/simulator it works fine, but not for real device.